# How can we override abstract class in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, overriding, abstract-class

I want to Override an abstract class of magento. ie `Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract`. My intention is to get rid of Telephone number validation.

I tried copying app/code/**core**/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php

To

app/code/**local**/Telephone/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php

Tried to Override the function validate() with new code.

```
public function validate()
    {
        $errors = array();
        $this->implodeStreetAddress();
        if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getFirstname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the first name.');
        }

        if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getLastname(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the last name.');
        }

        if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getStreet(1), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the street.');
        }

        if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getCity(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the city.');
        }

       /* if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getTelephone(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the phone number.');
        } */

        $_havingOptionalZip = Mage::helper('directory')->getCountriesWithOptionalZip();
        if (!in_array($this->getCountryId(), $_havingOptionalZip)
            && !Zend_Validate::is($this->getPostcode(), 'NotEmpty')
        ) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the zip/postal code.');
        }

        if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getCountryId(), 'NotEmpty')) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the country.');
        }

        if ($this->getCountryModel()->getRegionCollection()->getSize()
               && !Zend_Validate::is($this->getRegionId(), 'NotEmpty')
               && Mage::helper('directory')->isRegionRequired($this->getCountryId())
        ) {
            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please enter the state/province.');
        }

        if (empty($errors) || $this->getShouldIgnoreValidation()) {
            return true;
        }
        return $errors;
    }
```

But, I cant make it work!

Only way i can do it is by exactly copying the file to local folder. ie

app/code/**core/Mage**/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php

To

app/code/**local/Mage**/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php

and my config.xml in app/code/local/Customer/etc/ is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Telephone_Customer>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Telephone_Customer>
    </modules>

    <global>
    <models>
    <telephone_customer>
        <class>Telephone_Customer_Model</class>
    </telephone_customer>
    <customer>
        <rewrite>
            <customer>Telephone_Customer_Model_Customer</customer>
        </rewrite>
    <customer>
    </models>
    </global>   
</config>
```

But it is not allowed here bcz its not the right way to do it.

Can we override this abstract class like what we do in elsewhere..?

Please help.

Comment: class SomeClass extends Abstract{... ?

Comment: i tried it already. 

class Telephone_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract extends Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract {

}

But it doesnt work... :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it Finally.

I can access the

> function validate()

overriding derived classes such as Address.php.

ie overriding

> app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Address.php

Same principles we can use as i described in my code above to override the file.

Comment: Not a great approach. Use observers or config-based class rewrites to do this, otherwise you take ownership of lots of unrelated code & complicate the upgrade workflow.